# Does 'incomplete' mean the same thing in formal arithmetic compared to Godel's work?

Tags: first-order-logic, computability

I am struggling to understand what is different from 'Godel incompleteness' (GI) and call it 'ordinary completeness' (OC). Godel showed FOL to be complete. Yet, Godel's theorems establish that the language Q (an axiomatic extension of FOL) is incomplete.

What distinguishes GI from OC in terms of FOL?

Comment: Yes, this helps too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The completeness of first-order logic says that any sentence that is true in all models is provable. This is still true in a system like Robinson's system $Q$ that can model enough of natural number arithmetic for Gödel's incompleteness theorems to apply. The incompleteness theorems imply that there are sentences that are true in the **standard** model of arithmetic that cannot be proved: these sentences, e.g., a sentence $\mathrm{Con}(Q)$ that asserts the consistency of $Q$, will be false in certain non-standard models. Non-standard models include non-standard "numbers" that are greater than any number that can be obtained from $0$ by adding $1$ a finite number of times. A non-standard model can satisfy the axioms of $Q$, while admitting non-standard numbers that behave as if they were the Gödel number of a proof of the inconsistency of $Q$.

Comment: This helps. Thanks.